# Cannot paste text from clipboard into a comment

Tags: bug, ios-app

I was trying to copy a bug reference number from an email into a comment on a question, but it would not appear after tapping Paste. I tried copying several times, to no avail.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 11.0 (Build 15A372)